# Convert date in ISO YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to format date in ISO `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD` format using javascript.

I can convert current date string in  `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` format. For example `2016-01-11T02:40:33.117Z`. But I want to get like `2016-01-11T02:40:33.117+1100`.

Is it possible in javascript?

Comment: Please try to see whether this is closest to what you are looking for.       var local = new Date(); local.toUTCString();

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
var date = new Date(Date.now());
date.setTime(date.getTime() - (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
var output = date.toISOString().substring(0, date.toISOString().length - 1) + ((date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60) < 0 ? "-" : "+") + ((Math.abs(date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60) < 10) ?  ("0" + Math.abs(date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60)) : test) + "00";
```

The `output` variable should be close to what you are looking for. (the + and - may be inversed)

**NOTE:** There may exist a better solution; I will post it if I find it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCurrentDateFormated() {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime() - (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
  var timeZoneHours = date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
  var finalHours = Math.abs(timeZoneHours) < 10 ?
    timeZoneHours < 0 ? '-0' + timeZoneHours.toString().substring(1)
    : '+0' + timeZoneHours.toString().substring(1)
    : timeZoneHours;
  var timeZoneMin = ((timeZoneHours - Math.floor(timeZoneHours)) * 60) < 10 ?
    '0' + (timeZoneHours - Math.floor(timeZoneHours)) * 60 : (timeZoneHours - Math.floor(timeZoneHours)) * 60;
  var timeZone = finalHours + timeZoneMin;
  return date.toISOString().substring(0, 20) + date.getMilliseconds() + timeZone;
}
```